# Is there a way to hide all existing buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm studying python and just doing some small games and I'm stuck because I can't find anything about this topic.

I have 2 buttons and want both of them hide when any one of the two clicked. is there a way to do this?

here is my codes for the buttons inside the class `RedRidingHood`:

```
def p1Choice_a(self, event):
    print("You choose to run from the big wolf")
    event.widget.pack_forget()

def p1Choice_b(self, event):
    print("You choose to talk the big wolf")
    event.widget.pack_forget()
```

and here is the main start and creation of button also inside the class `RedRidingHood`:

```
def start(self):
    self.create_button_p1()

def create_button_p1(self, position):
    p1ca = Button(frame, text="A. Run from the big wolf")
    p1ca.bind('<Button-1>', self.p1Choice_a)
    p1ca.pack( side = LEFT )

    p1cb = Button(frame, text="B. Have a conversation with the big wolf")
    p1cb.bind('<Button-2>', self.p1Choice_b)
    p1cb.pack( side = RIGHT )


rrhStart = RedRidingHood()
rrhStart.start()
```

Comment: You make you button name global and hide then accordingly

Comment: @Sujay and how do I hide them if their names become global?

Comment: Check the answer and replace accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the functions

```
def create_button_p1(self, position):
    self.p1ca = Button(frame, text="A. Run from the big wolf")
    self.p1ca.bind('<Button-1>', self.p1Choice_a)
    self p1ca.pack( side = LEFT )

    self.p1cb = Button(frame, text="B. Have a conversation with the big wolf")
    self.p1cb.bind('<Button-2>', self.p1Choice_b)
    self.p1cb.pack( side = RIGHT )
```

And then these functions

```
def p1Choice_a(self, event):
    print("You choose to run from the big wolf")
    self.p1ca.pack_forget()
    self.p1cb.pack_forget()

def p1Choice_b(self, event):
    print("You choose to talk the big wolf")
    self.p1cb.pack_forget()
    self.p1ca.pack_forget()
```

Comment: both `self.p1ca.pack_forget()` and `self.p1cb.pack_forget()` should be inside `p1Choice_a` and `p1Choice_b`. and it works! thanks!

Comment: Yes, because it's a part of the class and it will work any in the class

Answer (score 0):

Use

`.pack_forget()`
`.grid_forget()`
`.place_forget()`

depending on which geometry manager you are using.